Is there an npm equivalent of `rails generate model` to create a new object type?
I'm wondering if there's an npm equivalent of rails generate model to create a new object type? I'm building a React app that uses nodejs/express/mysql as a backend.
I remember it being extremely simple to create a new model (ie custom object type), or edit an existing one with a few commands. Is there anything like that with my setup?
(I know I'll get in trouble for not providing code, so here's my server.js file. As you can see I already have an object called "users"):
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const errorHandler = require('_middleware/error-handler');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// api routes
app.use('/users', require('./users/users.controller'));

// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server listening on port ' + port));

Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to clarify the question :)

It is not clear what the functionality inside the users.controller.js file will be. Could you update your answer to show how you intend to extract data from the request and work with the database? Also, what package are you using to interact with your MySQL server? Are you using an entity framework like Sequelize, TypeORM or Prisma? This complexity may not be necessary for your project and you can do it without models.

I found https://plopjs.com/ to be a nice little tool for scaffolding new components/code snippets in a standardized manner.
